# Visual Studio 2015 task runner explorer missing bower task

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, bower, task-runner-explorer

In my ASP.NET 5 Web Application project using ASP.NET 5 Web Application template when I run Task Runner Explorer, I don't see the Bower task as shown in first figure of [this tutorial](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/knockout.html). Here is screenshot of my Task Runner Explorer:

[image]

Comment: What I find strange is that in the tutorial's screenshot it's actually a gruntfile, not a gulpfile. I also don't have a bower task 'magically' appearing in my TRE. So I don't know what that tutorial means exactly.